# Explain test behaviour - setProps doesn't change any properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my React Higher-ordered component but I am little confused. I am trying to change props but `setProps` doesn't change any properties.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import withToggle from './withToggle';
import MyComponent from "../MyComponent";

describe('HOC', () => {
  const MyComponentWrapper = withToggle(false)(MyComponent);

  it('should allows to set props', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponentWrapper />);
    console.log(wrapper.props()) // {val: false}
    wrapper.setProps({ val: true })
    console.log(wrapper.props()) // {val: false}
    expect(wrapper.prop('val')).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Where it sets props if not to the component that I test?

Comment: I need to understand the behavior. Where it sets props.

Comment: I know how to solve a problem, but I do not understand current behavior. My question is about current behavior. If you can explain "Where it sets props if not to the component that I test" then I will be so grateful!

Comment: What you posted to does seem like it works, however, the [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.md#common-gotchas) will give you an insight into what you need – dcodesmith 7 mins ago